# Computing 3D coordinates of a point in space using 3 or more cameras

Tags: math, camera, geometry

I'm working on this project where I need to know the "exact" coordinates in space of an object. I started looking for the answer with this paper: http://dsc.ijs.si/files/papers/S101%20Mrovlje.pdf

It describes how you can find the distance from the axis of two aligned cameras to the object. Great, so this gives me one distance I know, but I just know the distance from the axis and not the middle of the cameras, so I thought that wouldn't be too good if I don't have access to the distance from the middle of the camera.

So I thought, great, why not add two other cameras perpendicular to the first two. OK, so now, this gives me the coordinates in a plane.

Then I thought to myself, what if the cameras are not in the same plane, I could surely compute another distance, with one camera from the bottom plane and one from the upper plane, but this is where the problems start happening: Those cameras aren't aligned.

So two questions come to my mind:

- Is it possible to get formulas easy to use with cameras that aren't parallel?
- If it is, there would be a way to use only two cameras, right?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you only need two cameras to answer your question.

For now, assume that your cameras are located at `(100)` and `(010)`, and that you can find vectors pointing from each of your cameras to the point in question, say `(m1,m2,m3)` and `(n1,n2,n3)`. Then the point in question lies on the intersection of the two lines

```
(1,0,0) + s(m1,m2,m3)
(0,1,0) + t(n1,n2,n3)
```

From there, we obtain the system of equations

```
-m1 * s + n1 * t = 1
 m2 * s - n2 * t = 1
 m3 * s - n3 * t = 0
```

The system has 3 equations and 2 variables, but 2e know the system has a solution because there is a point at the intersection of the two lines. I recommend using Gaussian elimination to solve the system, but in most cases we can also proceed by simple elimination as follows:

```
s = (n3/m3) * t
m2 * (n3/m3) * t - n2 * t = 1
(m2 * n3 - n2 * m3)/m3 * t = 1
t = m3/(m2 * n3 - n2 * m3)
```

and the point in question is

```
(  (n1*m3)/(m2*n3-n2*m3), 1 + (n2*m3)/(m2*n3-n2*m3), (n3*m3)/(m2*n3-n2*m3) )
```

or doing a little bit of algebra,

```
(n1*m3, m2*n3, n3*m3)/(m2*n3-n2*m3)
```

That works most of the time, unless `m3=0` or `m2*n3-n2*m3=0`.

A similar calculation works for two cameras in general position; alternatively, you can use any linear transformation which takes your cameras to `(100)` and `(010)`, use the calculation above, and use the inverse transformation to take the result back to its original coordinates.

There are various pathologies and special cases (in particular, if the point lies on the axis determined by the two cameras, you can't find the point's position), but those will not show up with typical data. However, if you want a guarantee of being able to answer the question in all cases, you would need three non-collinear cameras.